# Why do I need to pass null as an argument in function.apply(null, arguments)?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying out some basic JS functionality:

```
function addUser(name, age, fun) {
    fun.apply(null, arguments); }

addUser("Peter",25, function(name) { console.log(name+"...from Function");});
```

but I just don't seem to understand why the first argument in `fun.apply(null, arguments);` needs to be `null`, and why I cannot simply do `fun.apply(arguments);` ?

Comment: Because that's not the [function signature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). You might as well ask _"Why cannot I simply do `addUser(25)`?"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `apply` is the `this` object. You don't have to pass `null`, you could pass `this` or any other object as well, but you can't just pass `arguments` by itself because then `arguments` will become your `this` object in the function and `name` won't get a value.

Note that, for this example, you could just call `fun(name)` instead of `fun.apply(null, arguments)`.